# Conditional SQL select: when select has a value select all but the smallest date

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking at the following SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/962496/1

How could one select all orders from user b@b.cn with userpk = 2 and reg = 1 but only
the two most recent orders from a@a.cn with userpk = 1 and reg = 0. So the query will show 3 orders for userpk = 2 but only 2 orders (not the earliest order 2012-01-01 from userpk = 1

So the condition would be reg, if reg = 0 then ignore first order

Comment: You question is unanswerable.  Your SQL Fiddle example has not column called "reg" and no table or column related to "order".  Please fix the SQL Fiddle.  You can also put the table definitions in the question.

Comment: Fiddle fixed, table users has column reg and relation to orders is via uPK (userpk in users)

Comment: the most recent orders are always the two most recents? your question don't help

Comment: only ignore the earliest order?

Comment: yes, basically if reg = 0 then ignore first order since i suppose it's an order with a specific one-time state. i think bluefeet's answer is basically what i'm looking for. i will have to try in the original database which is a lot more complex. but help here has been tremendous so far!

Comment: yeah @bluefeet solved it, accept his answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will give you the result that you want:

```
select *
from users u
left join another a
  on u.userpk = a.uPK
where
(
  u.userpk = 2
  and u.reg = 1
)
or
(
  u.userpk = 1
  and u.reg = 0
  and a.odate not in (select min(odate)
                      from another a1
                      where u.userpk = a1.uPK)
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/387b5/6)

A version not specific to single users (if you have more than 2 users):

```
select *
from users u
left join another a
  on u.userpk = a.uPK
where
(
   u.reg = 1
)
or
(
  u.reg = 0
  and a.odate not in (select min(odate)
                      from another a1
                      where u.userpk = a1.uPK)
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/387b5/7)

Comment: can I reference the alias u in there "where" here because it's a new select statement? I still don't understand why I cannot use alias in where regularly but here it works.

Comment: @BenSchnitzel this is a table alias, so yes you can use it. You cannot use column aliases in a `WHERE` clause unless it is part of a derived table or subquery.

Comment: thanks alot you have really helped alot the last few days bluefeet :D i will finish this problem tomorrow and tell the results here